# Write output to two files, overwrite the first one, append to the second one

Tags: shell

I want to write the output of a script to two files. Overwriting the first file but appending to the second one.

I'm currently doing:

```
echo Foo Bar | tee -a one.txt | tee -a two.txt
```

But this appends `Foo Bar` to both files.

Example:

Before

```
cat one.txt
#=> Bar Foo

cat two.txt
#=> Hello world
```

After

```
cat one.txt
#=> Foo Bar

cat two.txt
#=> Hello world
    Foo Bar
```

How do I do this with a single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are very close the answer already.

`tee -a` means to append. Without `-a` means to overwrite.

```
echo Foo Bar | tee one.txt | tee -a two.txt
```